# $f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin ^2 x-\cos 2x, &0 <x \leq \frac{\pi}{4}\\[2ex] a\tan x+b\sin 2x \ \ &\frac{\pi}{4} <x<\frac{\pi}{2}, & \end{cases}$

Tags: calculus

Let 
$a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\sin ^2 x-\cos 2x,  &0 <x \leq \frac{\pi}{4}\\[2ex]
a\tan x+b\sin 2x  \ \ &\frac{\pi}{4} <x<\frac{\pi}{2}, & 
\end{cases}$ differentiable at $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ then find $b$ .

---

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}^+}\frac{a\tan x+b\sin 2x-\frac{1}{2}}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}=l$$

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}^-}\frac{\sin^2x-\cos 2x-\frac{1}{2}}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}=l'$$

we have $l=l'$

---

Now what ?

Comment: the function should also be continuous so equate both values at that point

Comment: If the function differentiable in point `x` means that it has left and right derivative in (`x-0`, `x+0` correspondingly), and they are *equal*. Also function  function should be continuous at x.

Answer (score 1):

Setting both original functions equal to each other and evaluating at $x=\pi/4$ yields $a+b=1/2$.

Differentiating both functions we have $$2sin(x)cos(x)+2sin(2x)$$ and $$asec^2(x)+2bcos(2x)$$
Evalutaing both functions at $x=\pi/4$ and setting them equal yeilds $a=3/2$.
Thus $b=-1$.